# Is there a "this project" or "this assembly" alias for Imports?

Tags: vb.net, namespaces

```
Public Class A
    Public Class B ... End Class
    Public Class C ... End Class
End Class
```

I'm writing some utility code that makes heavy use of B and C, so up at the top I did `Imports ThisProject.A`. Great, until I want to use that file in `ThatProject`. I normally *link* to code like this, so changing it breaks the other project.

I thought `Namespace` was the fix, but that adds another layer to the space, so the project name is still there. Did I do this wrong?

Alternately, is there syntax for "this project" in Imports?

Comment: A project has a root namespace.  You can make it an empty string, but the odds that you won't shoot your leg off are rather low.  This is one bad practice begetting another, don't duplicate source files in projects.  The .NET Framework makes it dead-simple to use a class from another assembly.

Comment: Well instead of the empty string, what about just using the same root namespace in the different projects? Is there any reason not to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
apple.vb
    Namespace ThisProject.Foo
        Public Class Apple
        ' stuff
        End Class
    End Namespace

orange.vb
    Namespace ThisProject.Foo
        Public Class Orange
        ' other stuff
        End Class
    End Namespace

banana.vb
    Namespace ThisProject.Foo
        Public Class Banana
        ' yet more stuff
        End Class
    End Namespace

(ThisProject)someotherclass.vb
    Imports Foo
    ' other stuff in the class
    Private Sub Blah()
        Dim x as new Banana()
    End Sub

(ThatProject)yetanotherclass.vb
    Imports ThisProject.Foo
    ' other functions, etc
    Private Sub Cool()
        Dim y as new Orange()
    End Sub
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong - that last example, I have to `Imports ThatProject.ThisProject.Foo`. And yes, it *is* in my imported namespaces.